# Not able to step into native code - Android

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface, android-studio-2.2

I have been trying to debug the native code on Android studio.
My debugger runs fine on simple hello world jni code.
But when I try to do the same with the code that is linked with shared lib libcrypto.so and libccmssl.so , I am not able to step into the native code.

Now I am not sure if the above observation is any important. But I am not sure where to explore next. While Loading the library I am getting following (attached image) SIGILL, after which, on pressing continue, the code runs, the native functions are called and values returned, but the debugger does not step into native code.

[image]

Any pointers what I should look at would be appreciated, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to get an external c++ project work with android studio since a week now and trying to narrow down the reason --> "Why I am not able to step into the native code "

For me the problem was presence of  "-gstabs+" flag in LOCAL_CPPFLAGS
I removed it --> build --> and Yay

Following is the flags description:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

-gstabs+
Produce debugging information in stabs format (if that is supported), using GNU extensions understood only by the GNU debugger (GDB). ***The use of these extensions is likely to make other debuggers crash or refuse to read the program.***

Note: the above SIGILL image that I posted in the question still persist, but it was not what was causing debugger to not step it.

Comment: The SIGILL comes from OpenSSL trying to discover CPU features by using them. It happens on ARM but you can safely skip it.